# Visual Studio breaks on Handled Exception as if it was Unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I use Activator.CreateInstance to create class from Type. In case where constructor throws exception (That happens and is totally expected) it is caught by try..catch.
But Visual Studio breaks as if it was unhandled.
I managed to simplify this issue:
[Screenshot of VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLJek.png)
[Code in Tio](https://tio.run/##PU7LqsJADF07XxFcTRf2B8SFiIKgcOEu7nqM0QbqpGRivUX67XWsxSzyOsk5B9MCRWkY7onjFX67ZHRbutk7XHM/1YyAdUgJflSuGm7u6QAmIFmwXFrhMxwDR19k7I0DmHZTB9AGhYsIrGCNxm0w0XKjFIz2MVNEJG9dQ3LxO5GiWI5vGAwrePbjsJGYpKbyT9nowJH8fMeRU0Xn@Xjfu1nOH6OZZJKebOaFL75urFJ5QKQHbP@RGmPJvj@a/cjUD8ML)

```cs
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try {
      var foo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo));
    catch {}
    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
  }

  class Foo {
    public Foo() {
      throw new Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

*If that's important I use Visual Studio 2019*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code with your question, not as a link.

Comment: There's nothing that handles the exception in `Foo`. So it's unhandled. It's not exactly `Main` that is initializing a new instance of `Foo`. If you change that line to `var foo = new Foo();`, you should catch it (but you have an empty `catch` block), since `Main` is calling the constructor of `Foo` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because you are debugging your code, even Visual Studio says that the exception is handled.

It is configurable. Go to "Debug -> Windows -> Exception handling" window and uncheck all exceptions in "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" (or leave some if you want to see them even if it is handled).

Another VS settings that may cause it - Options->Debuggin->"Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" enabled

Comment: But it says "Exception User-Unhandled"

Comment: @wokarol, another VS settings that may cause it - Options->Debuggin->"Break when exceptions cross AppDomain or managed/native boundaries" enabled. It makes sense in your case because you're using Activator in order to create a new instance.

Comment: It's unticked, any other idea?