# Prevent code break in try-catch block using vb.net in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Try-catch block don't work as expected. In Java, if I wrote something similar and an exception occur in the "Try" code, the program executes the "catch" code.

Now, let's do an example:

```
try
    'I want to read an integer from file
    FileGet(aFile, anInteger)
Catch ex as Exception
    'If there is an error, i show a console message
    Console.writeLine("Exception")
End Try
```

If I run this code (it's an example... I've this problem with every try-catch), I get a *"System.IO.EndOfStreamException"* and the program stop itself in the try code. I can go in the catch block with *f5* or *f11* (I'm using Visual Studio 2019), but I suppose the exception shouldn't be raised.

Now, I suppose that the problem is in my Visual Studio *"Exception Settings"*: I've the default settings and I checked *"Common Language Runtime Exception"*. Is there a way to avoid code breaking when an exception occurrs in a try-catch block?

I've also read this [answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11183553/6584029), but it can't solve my problem because I can't find the User-unhandled exceptions checkbox. Also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58466136/visual-studio-breaks-on-handled-exception-as-if-it-was-unhandled) doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: This is the default behavior for many exception while debugging. When the exception is raised, VS asks you if you want to break on that exception (every time), so just deselect it at that time or before that, using the Exception Settings pane.

Comment: When the exception is thrown, i can disable the checkbox "Break when this exception TYPE is thrown"... But I want to disable only the unhandled exception. If the same exception occurs in another part of the code and there isn't a try-catch block, I want the execution to break!

Comment: I'm probably missing something: isn't that the default behavior when you have deselected `Break when this exception type is thrown`? Are you in debug mode? At run-time, you have to handle the `UnhandledException` (adding the event handler to `MyApplication` or overriding `OnUnhandledException`), if you're using the Application Framework. Otherwise as in C# (in `Main`).

Comment: You're looking for Debug / Windows / Exception Settings if you want to control how the debugger reacts.

Comment: Here's a document you may need:[Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)